# Avoiding PostBack OnClientClick event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback, onclientclick

I've below `asp buttons` in `radAjax:RadAjaxPanel` control which has `OnClientClick` event -

```
<radAjax:RadAjaxPanel ID="Panel" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="Loadingpanel6">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Sort by :</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMostRecent" Text="Most Recent" class="button action sortcomments"
                        runat="server" OnCommand="btnMostRecent_Click" OnClientClick="(document.getElementById('hdnSortOrder')).value='date'" CommandArgument="date" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMostViewed" Text="Most Viewed" class="Comments" runat="server"
                        OnCommand="btnMostViewed_Click" OnClientClick="(document.getElementById('hdnSortOrder')).value='views'" CommandArgument="views" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<radAjax:AjaxLoadingPanel ID="Loadingpanel6" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="Loading" BorderWidth="0px" ImageUrl="/themes/mercolaarticle/images/loading6.gif" />
    </radAjax:AjaxLoadingPanel>
</radAjax:AjaxLoadingPanel>
```

When i `click` on any of the `button` the page `PostBack` which i want to `avoid`.

**FYI** - `Buttons` are in `RadAjaxPanel`.

Any `suggestion` or `help`.!!
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: You may use UpdatePanel, I think it is best solution in your case. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx
http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Answer (score 0):

Return false in OnClientClick i.e. -

```
OnClientClick="(document.getElementById('hdnSortOrder')).value='views'; return false;"
```

Be aware that this means post back will never occur on that button.

Comment: @Pranav The edit you made to the questions changes things significantly. I am not familiar with Telerik controls. Have you viewed this documentation? - [link](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxpanel/client-side-programming/client-side-events/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you return false from your client click function then postback will not happen.

like

```
 <asp:button runat="server" id="btn" OnClientClick="return myFunc();"/>
```

and script block is

```
 <script>

 function myFunc()

   {

    return false;

     }

         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
 <asp:button runat="server" id="btn" OnClientClick="myFunc(); return false;"/>
```

and then:

```
<script>

 function myFunc(){

    //Do your javascript code here

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid postback from button control just simply return false from you function.

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnTest" OnClientClick="anyFunction() return false;"/>
```